# How to get all attributes of an object and the attributes of its subobjects?

Tags: python

How to use a pythonic way to get all attribute of instance `f` and get do the same to just obtained attribute.

I want to get `['__init__', 'own', 'Meta', 'field']`, no matter the order.

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.own = 'own'

    class Meta:
        field = None


f = Foo()
print(dir(f))

I want to get all attributes of f and the attributes of its subobjects.

if specific_attr in attrs:
    do_something
```

When i use `dir(f)`, i got too much value, filtering from this seems a bit troublesome and there is no `attribute 'field'`, i need to use `dir(f.Meta)` again.

I want an easy way to get all attributes of instance `f` and the attributes of its subobjects, my purpose is:

`if specific_attr in attrs: do_something`

Comment: `print(dir(f))`. Did you try this?

Comment: yes, I have tried it, but there is no 'a', and there are many other properties.

Comment: `dir` returns all the properties and attributes of a given object. I don't understand why `test.for_test is specified` so. It should either be a class variable or an instance variable. Then you will be able to see those attributes in the `dir` output. `test` is not an object but a method. why do you use the dot operator there? If you want to declare that as an instance variable use `self.for_test=1`

Comment: I have modified the question, even use class Meta instead of test(), I still can't get `field` from `dir(f)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
print(dir(Foo))
```

This should give you the list of properties you want.

Comment: It give me too much, but no 'a' in it.

Comment: I don't undestand what is `a` used for there, when is not defined anywhere...